# $I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: calculus

I have to find $$I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$ Can someone help me to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried  differentiating under the integral sign? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried $t=\arctan(\alpha x)\,.$ but i can't sovle it

Comment: @Tuanlee, you should probably add some context and elaborate on your own attempts

Comment: The answer should be $$\large \frac{\pi}{2}\operatorname{arcsinh}(\alpha).$$                       It also follows from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795493/integral-int-01-log-frac1ax1-ax-fracdxx-sqrt1-x2-pi-arcsin-a) with $a\mapsto i a$.

Comment: can you explain carefully?

Answer (score 2):

$$I'(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+\alpha^2 x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1+\alpha^2\sin^2\theta}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}} $$
by the tangent half-angle substitution. By integrating with respect to $\alpha$:

> $$ I(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(\alpha x)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\text{arcsinh}(\alpha)}.$$